# Unable to play Hat Dash in Safari 14

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020, hat-dash

When Hat Dash is launched in Safari (by pressing the space bar), the unicorn stays static. Pressing the space bar further does nothing.

[image]

- Browser: Version 14.0.1 (15610.2.11.51.10, 15610)
- OS: macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Note: It works perfectly when running in Chrome.

---

Error shown in the console when pressing the space bar after Hat Dash is launched.

```
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: AudioContext
    loadSounds (hd.min.js:1:7817)
    onKeyDown (hd.min.js:1:13926)
    (anonymous function) (hd.min.js:1:12781)
    (anonymous function)
```

Comment: The same problem also occurs in Edge Legacy. Maybe the fix for Safari will also fix it there; if not, I'll file a new bug report. (By the way, the legacy EdgeHTML-based Microsoft Edge is supported by SE.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**: This is now working, thanks to some long-distance debugging [help from Panda](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357936/unable-to-play-hat-dash-in-safari-14/358000#comment1195876_358000)

> Safari on Mac
> Why do you hate audio
> Muted now, play on

---

So…I do my development work on a Windows machine. And when I try to download Safari to debug the issue, I get this:

[image: Screenshot of text from Apple saying that Safari for Windows is not longer updated]

The whole game is in JavaScript, so if there are any developer console errors happening that you can provide and help me with debugging, we can *try* to fix this. But no promises.

Comment: I've updated my post to include the error shown in the dev console, thanks for looking into it!

Comment: ahh, so Safari doesnt like sound. I'll see if I can put an exclusion there.

Comment: Can you [go here](http://wayou.github.io/t-rex-runner/) and see if this game will run, and if it plays sounds? or same error there?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't run and there's no sound. Shows `[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: AudioContext` in console.

Comment: Please put `window.navigator.platform` into your dev console and tell me what comes out

Comment: `"MacIntel" = $1`

Comment: Not that it helps but to make you feel less guilty of not having Safari for Windows: If you navigate in 5.1.7 to any SE site you receive the message: *can't establish a secure connection to the server*. Not being able to download that browser saved you another headache ....